Fourier transform processing of iq data
I want to perform fourier transform on the iq data that is taken from spectrum analyzer. The purpose is to estimate phase noise from iq data.

Hi and Welcome to DSP.SE. My first impulse was to say: Do it. Nevertheless, you should be aware that you are not asking anything, only stating what you want to do. It is totally unclear which problem you are facing, why you are facing it and what you have tried to overcome it. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.
